# jsonexception value <br of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonarray

Tags: android, arrays, android-volley

i need to show post of user .. i make recyclerview 
and php file when you pass a user_id you get your post in RecyclerView .. 
For testing i made php file get all posts of users and worked successfully, 
but when i make php file when you are passing a user_id it worked on post man and get result as array [postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFhRl.png)

its the same result of first php file that get all posts 
but in android php file one get result and show it in recyclerview with no problem 
with seconed php file give me a message "jsonexception value

thats my java code

```
private void load(){

    final String user_id=SharedPref.getInstance(getActivity()).getid();
    RequestQueue rq= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    JsonArrayRequest jar=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.MyPOST_URL,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    for(int x=0;x<response.length();x++)
                    {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj=response.getJSONObject(x);

                            location=obj.getString("location");
                            description=obj.getString("description");
                            bloodtype=obj.getString("bloodtype");
                            number=obj.getString("number");
                            date=obj.getString("created_at");



                            GetMyPost data=new GetMyPost(description,location,bloodtype,number,date);

                            data_list.add(data);

                            rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

                            adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),data_list);
                            rv.setAdapter(adapter);

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    )
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user_id",user_id);

            return params;
        }

    };
    rq.add(jar);

}
```

i get user_id from sharedpref i tested it and return my id with no problem 
please help me

Comment: Either you have error in the php or the data you are sending to server. If you can print that string response starting with <br it will show on which line on php the error occurs

Comment: how can i print the response starting with <br ??? please

Comment: If you can give me that URL and sample JSON data to post, I may be able to help

Answer (score 0):

send params to server

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

 try {
        params.put("user_id", user_id);
        JSONObject JsonObj = new JSONObject(params);
        JsonArrayRequest jar=new JsonArrayRequest
        (Request.Method.POST,
                Constants.MyPOST_URL  ,
                JsonObj,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try{
                             getData_and_set_Model(response);
                        }catch (Exception ex){
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(productActivity.this,"VolleyError : " + 
                    error.getMessage()+ "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                    
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectReq);
    }catch (Exception ex){}
```

and

```
create class AppController  extends Application
```

in AndroidManifest >

> ```
> > <application
> >         android:name=".AppController"
> > 
> > <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> ```

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static AppController mInstance;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;       
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

you problem is send server

Tell me if it is not resolved

Comment: can you give me full code of function ?? pleeeeeeease

Comment: my function that load data is private void load() { }